# React filter still outputting filtered values

Tags: reactjs, filter, null

I am trying to filter an array of objects where the value of name is blank or null. However, the name values that contain - "" - are still rendering to the browser.
Can you please look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
import NameList from './NameList.js';

const ItemTable = (props) => {

    const filteredNames = props.items.filter(function (item) {
        return item.name !== null || item.name !== "";
    });

    return (
        <ul>
            {filteredNames.map((item) => (
            <NameList
                key={item.id}
                listId={item.listId}
                name={item.name}
            />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
    
}

export default ItemTable;
```

Comment: you need && not ||

Comment: you can also do `function(item){ return item.name }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!!value` will check if the variable in value has valid contents OR not.
You also don't need to create another unwanted array. Can render directly.

```
import NameList from "./NameList.js";

const ItemTable = (props) => (
  <ul>
    {
      props.items.map((item) => (
        !!item.name ?
          <NameList key={item.id} listId={item.listId} name={item.name} /> 
        : 
          null
      ))
    }
  </ul>
);

export default ItemTable;
```